# pandas add group number use a loop

Tags: python, pandas

Giving the format:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Time_diff':[1400,1200,1000,1800,1200,1200,1200,1800,1200]})
```

There is a column "time_diff", I am trying to add group number in a new column "gourp_num", and the group number will increase one when it meets a condition : Time_diff > 1800. As shown below:

| Time_diff | group_num |
| --- | --- |
| 1400 | 1 |
| 1200 | 1 |
| 1000 | 1 |
| 1800 | 2 |
| 1200 | 2 |
| 1200 | 2 |
| 1200 | 2 |
| 1800 | 3 |
| 1200 | 3 |

I wrote a loop but it doesn't work, what should I do?

```
a=1
for i in range(1,len(df)):
    if df[i]['time_diff'] < 1800:
        df[i]['group_num']=a
    else:
        a+=1
        df[i]['group_num']=a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for condition `time_diff` >= 1800 by [`.ge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html) and use [`.cumsum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) to increment the count whenever the condition fulfills again down the series:

```
df['group_num'] = df['Time_diff'].ge(1800).cumsum() + 1
```

Result:

```
print(df)

   Time_diff  group_num
0       1400          1
1       1200          1
2       1000          1
3       1800          2
4       1200          2
5       1200          2
6       1200          2
7       1800          3
8       1200          3
```

If you want to have unique group numbers, the codes above work well to support this.  However, if you want the group number `group_num` always starts with 1 even when the first `Time_diff` in the series (row 0) is 1800 (even your looping codes don't handle this boundary/edge case), you can fine-tune it a bit, as follows:

```
# To ensure always starts with 1, add 1 only when the first value is not 1800

df['group_num'] = df['Time_diff'].ge(1800).cumsum() + int(df['Time_diff'][0] != 1800)
```

Comment: Simple and effective solution, learnt something new :)

Comment: I didnt ask the question, but I did upvote

Comment: @HaimingWang See my edit above to ensure the the group number always starts with 1 even when the first `Time_diff` is already 1800.

Comment: Thanks for the modification! and I have accepted it now.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code to get the expected solution using for loop

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'Time_diff':[1400,1200,1000,1800,1200,1200,1200,1800,1200]})
a=1
group_num = []
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Time_diff'] < 1800:
        group_num.append(a)
    else:
        a+=1
        group_num.append(a)
df['group_num']=group_num
print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

output

```
Time_diff  group_num
      1400          1
      1200          1
      1000          1
      1800          2
      1200          2
      1200          2
      1200          2
      1800          3
      1200          3
>
```